# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present

what i am missing? i add wdsl-addressing programatically:

```
wsbp.setOutboundHeaders( new StringHeader(WS_ADDR_VER.messageIDTag, uuid), replyTo.createHeader(WS_ADDR_VER.replyToTag));
```

i am using jdeveloper 11g

CODE:

```
asyncNarociloServisService = new AsyncNarociloServisService();
AsyncNarociloServis asyncNarociloServis = asyncNarociloServisService.getAsyncNarociloServisPort();


// Get the request context to set the outgoing addressing properties
WSBindingProvider wsbp = (WSBindingProvider)asyncNarociloServis;
WSEndpointReference replyTo = new WSEndpointReference("http://84.255.215.133:7101/TestniWS-TestniWS-context-root/AsyncNarociloServisResponseImplPort", WS_ADDR_VER);
String uuid = "uuid:" + UUID.randomUUID();

wsbp.setOutboundHeaders( new StringHeader(WS_ADDR_VER.messageIDTag, uuid), replyTo.createHeader(WS_ADDR_VER.replyToTag));
```

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
     name="AsyncNarociloServisService"
     targetNamespace="http://www.xxx.si/narocilowsdl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
     xmlns:tns="http://www.xxx.si/narocilowsdl"
     xmlns:nar="http://www.xxx.si/narocilo"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
     xmlns:pov="http://www.xxx.si/povratnica"
    >
    <plnk:partnerLinkType name="AsyncNarociloServis">
        <plnk:role name="AsyncNarociloServisProvider">
            <plnk:portType name="tns:AsyncNarociloServis"/>
        </plnk:role>
        <plnk:role name="AsyncNarociloServisRequestor">
            <plnk:portType name="tns:AsyncNarociloServisResponse"/>
        </plnk:role>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.xxx.si/narocilo" schemaLocation="narocilo.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.xxx.si/povratnica" schemaLocation="povratnica.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="obdelajNarociloResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="pov:povratnica"/>
    </message>
    <message name="obdelajNarocilo">
        <part name="parameters" element="nar:narocilo"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="AsyncNarociloServisResponse">
        <operation name="obdelajNarociloOperationResponse">
            <input message="tns:obdelajNarociloResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <portType name="AsyncNarociloServis">
        <operation name="obdelajNarociloOperation">
            <input message="tns:obdelajNarocilo"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="AsyncNarociloServisResponsePortBinding" type="tns:AsyncNarociloServisResponse">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="obdelajNarociloOperationResponse">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <binding name="AsyncNarociloServisPortBinding" type="tns:AsyncNarociloServis">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="obdelajNarociloOperation">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="AsyncNarociloServisService">
        <port name="AsyncNarociloServisPort" binding="tns:AsyncNarociloServisPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.xxx.si:9088/ServicesG/services/AsyncNarociloServisPort"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

EDIT:

request

```
<S:Header>
    <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">??</To>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">??</Action>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:c839d6f4-2c33-4f5b-b001-7ce9869a3aa3</MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsa:Address>http://84.255.215.133:7101/TestniWS-TestniWS-context-root/AsyncNarociloServisResponseImplPort</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
  </S:Header>
  <S:Body>
```

what to be in ??

Comment: I added a link in my answer, did you try to add the Action tag of the WS-Addressing header?

Comment: yes i was missing action. Now is ok but i do not know what to add in action? our repl WS or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a WS-Adressing header.
I think that's what the message says.

I don't know what's the framework you use for your Web Service call but here is an example using the CXF as framework: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-addressing.html.

Maybe take a look at this article: http://log.illsley.org/2006/10/05/a-required-header-representing-a-message-addressing-property-is-not-present/.

You can try something like:

```
<Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.kemofarmacija.si/narocilowsdl:obdelajNarociloOperation</Action>
<MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:8ff3f2f0-6548-4411-8075-98af3cc23a1b</MessageID>
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://elona2.kemofarmacija.si:9088/ServicesG/services/AsyncNarociloServisPort</To>
<ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
</ReplyTo>
```

Comment: OK, I don't know how to activate WS-Addressing for JDeveloper, if there is no specific configuration maybe you can set the needed information directly on the SOAP Header...

Comment: i figure out what is the problem. i was missing <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">??</Action>

Comment: Try to add the your server's service name prefixed by its namespace.

Comment: You can try something like:
'<Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.kemofarmacija.si/narocilowsdl:obdelajNarociloOperation</Action>
<MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:8ff3f2f0-6548-4411-8075-98af3cc23a1b</MessageID>
<To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">SERVICE_URL</To>
<ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
</ReplyTo>'

Comment: can you poste me as an answer becouse here are some fileds hidden. Thx

Comment: just one more question. This is async web service and i need to get reply. But in your example there is no web service in "reply to" to reply. How can i get reply then from async ws. Thx

Comment: Maybe you can set a valid reply address instead if an anonymous one as in my example.

Comment: you mean valid web service or something else

Comment: I think you should use the address to the service that waits for the server response. This is kind of your client address.

Comment: so http://84.255.215.133:7101/TestniWS-TestniWS-context-root/AsyncNarociloServisResponseImplPort was ok in my example